# How to use WHERE - LIKE cluase in yii2 and make LIKE pattern search with case sensitivity?

Tags: php, yii2, where-clause, sql-like

```php
$aa = India::find();
$players = $aa
            ->where('player LIKE :query', [':query'=>'S%'])
            ->orderBy('position, player')->all();
$countnumber = $aa->count();
```

This code returns results without case sensitivity.
Gives results where Player name starts with 'S' or 's'.

But I want to make, just to select Player names only with 'S'.
How to restrict it to select with case sensitivity in PHP Yii2 Framworok ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case you are using MySQL you can make your query with [BINARY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/binary-varbinary.html)

So your Yii2 code should be something like this:

```
$players = India::find()
            ->where(['LIKE BINARY', 'player', $query_parameter])
            ->orderBy('position, player')->all();
```

Comment: LIKE BINARY WORKED

Done the work.
Thank you.